# How to make Image responsive without javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

There are numerous ways to implement responsive images in webpages. However, all solutions I came across make use of JavaScript.How to implement responsive images without the use of JavaScript? Can we implement image responsive purey by CSS.

UPDATE
I did some research before posting this question. - 
- https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill
- http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/
- http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Could you describe what you're trying to accomplish in a bit more detail?

Comment: Why you don't wanna use JavaScript

Comment: Define 'responsive images'. Do you want to server lower quality versions of images to smaller/lower-resolution browsers/devices to save bandwidth, or do you just want to scale your image down client-side? Or something else?

Comment: Not at all happy with the downvote. I did some research before posting this question.
- http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/
- http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/
- http://www.shutterstock.com/blog/2013/05/how-to-use-responsive-images-to-make-your-site-shine-on-any-platform/

Comment: @AnupKhandelwal The downvotes are because the question isn't sufficiently clear for us to be able to understand what you want or answer you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unbelievable simple. Just use a % based width and the image will fill XX% of its container.

Set a container % based width to entire wrapper based on viewport size.

Note: not compatible with HTML5 doctype. If HTML5, use CSS declaration `width:50%;` as Markus suggests in the comments.

`<img src="file.jpg" width="50%" alt="caption" />`

Comment: You might as well use css `width:50%;`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in css make the image to always have heights according to the size of containers

```
img
{
height:100%;
width:100%
}
```